# VB challenge/ help MONTE CARLO INTEGRATION

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Im trying to create Monte-Carlo simulation that can be used to derive estimates for integration problems (summing up the area under
a curve). Have no idea what to do now and i am stuck

"to solve this problem we generate a number (say n) of random number pairs for x and y between 0 and 1, for each pair we see if the point (x,y) falls above or below the line. We count the number of times this happens (say c). The area under the curve is computed as c/n"

Really confused please help thank you

```
Function MonteCarlo()

    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim x As Double
    Dim func As Double
    Dim total As Double
    Dim result As Double
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim N As Integer

    Console.WriteLine("Enter a")
    a = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter b")
    b = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter n")
    N = Console.ReadLine()

    For j = 1 To N
        'Generate a new number between a and b
        x = (b - a) * Rnd()

        'Evaluate function at new number 
        func = (x ^ 2) + (2 * x) + 1

        'Add to previous value 
        total = total + func

    Next j

    result = (total / N) * (b - a)
    Console.WriteLine(result)
    Console.ReadLine()
    Return result

End Function
```

Comment: You should use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx). It will point out some type mismatches in your code (e.g. you could use `Integer.Parse()` to convert from the input strings into the integers required. **Then**, please tell us what the problem is, e.g. it gives the wrong result (if that is the case) rather than just "I am stuck."

Answer (score 0):

You are using the rejection method for MC area under the curve.

Do this:

1. Divide the range of x into, say, 100 equally-spaced, non-overlapping bins.
2. For your function y = f(x) = (x ^ 2) + (2 * x) + 1, generate e.g. 10,000 values of y for 10,000 values of x = (b - a) * Rnd().
3. Count the number of y-values in each bin, and divide by 10,000 to get a "bin probability." --> p(x).
4. Next, the proper way to randomly simulate your function is to use the rejection method, which goes as follows:

   4a.  Draw a random x-value using x = (b - a) * Rnd()

   4b.  Draw a random uniform U(0,1).  If U(0,1) is less than p(x) add a count to the bin.

   4c.  Continue steps 4a-4b 10000 times.

You will now be able to simulate your y=f(x) function using the rejection method.

Overall, you need to master these approaches before you do what you want since it sounds like you have little experience in bin counts, simulation, etc.  Area under the curve is always one using this approach, so just be creative for integrating using MC.

Look at some good textbooks on MC integration.